# How do you increment a bit of a bit-array from a position in array?

Tags: bit-manipulation, common-lisp, bitarray

I would like to (modulo) increment a particular bit of a bit-array. How do you do that in Common Lisp ?

For example, I want to increment the value of bit 3 in bit-array #*0001
(The bit 3 has the value 1). I want to modulo-increment it by 1, so that it would turn to 0.

```
CL-USER> (setf x #*0001)
#*0001

CL-USER> (bit x 3)
1 (1 bit, #x1, #o1, #b1)

CL-USER> (setf (bit x 3) (+ (bit x 3) 1))
TYPE-ERROR :
The value
  2
is not of type
  BIT
when setting an element of (ARRAY BIT)
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

Of course, I have the same error when using INCF instead of SETF.
I want a modulo-increment, that is I don't want #*0001 to turn to #*0010 but to be #*0000.

I have an error when using NOT in :

```
CL-USER> (setf (bit x 3) (not (bit x 3)))

Value of #:NEW1 in ((SETF AREF) #:NEW1 #:G0 3) is NIL, not a BIT.
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]
```

All the same, when using LOGNOT:

```
CL-USER> (setf (bit x 3) (lognot (bit x 3)))

Value of (LOGNOT (BIT X 3)) in
((SETF AREF) #:NEW1 #:G0 3)
is
  -2,
not a
  BIT.
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]
```

I don't see how I could use BIT-NOT as it wants 2 bit-arrays as input. I just want to invert (modulo-increment) a bit in a bit-array from its position in the bit array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "literal" way to do this would be something like

```lisp
(defvar *array* (make-array 4 :element-type 'bit :initial-element 0))
(setf (bit *array* 2) (mod (1+ (bit *array* 2)) 2))
(print *array*) ;; ==> #*0010
(setf (bit *array* 2) (mod (1+ (bit *array* 2)) 2))
(print *array*) ;; ==> #*0000
```

or as self-contained function:

```lisp
(defun nbit-flip (bitset index)
  (setf (bit bitset index) (mod (1+ (bit bitset index)) 2))
  bitset)
```

You could use `(logxor 1 ...)` to do the flipping like

```lisp
(defun nbit-flip (bitset index)
  (setf (bit bitset index) (logxor 1 (bit bitset index)))
  bitset)
```

Just stick to that which signals your intention most clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You need the result to be a `bit` and since CL tries to do correct arithmetic this means you need to actually make it be a `bit` as `bit`s aren't closed under addition.  An obvious approach is

```
(setf (bit a ...) (mod (+ (bit a ...) increment) 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

- `not` is only for logical values and returns either T or NIL (`boolean`
  type).
- `(lognot 1)` is -2 (two's complement) the negative sign is there because integers have no fixed width (they can be arbitrary long), and you need to mask the result to a particular width to obtain a positive value. Since you are using bit values, you can simply combine it with `logand` as follows:

  ```
  (logand (lognot 0) 1) => 1
  (logand (lognot 1) 1) => 0
  ```
- `logxor` as explained in another answer is fine too
- you could also compute `(- 1 b)`:

  ```
   (defun bit1+ (b)
    (declare (type bit b))
    (the bit (- 1 b)))
  ```

In any case, you can also define a bit-increment macro:

```
(defmacro bitincf (place)
  `(setf ,place (bit1+ ,place)))
```